# How to show total as well as distributed total among categories

Tags: dashboard, ux-integration, combobox

There is a total section on my dashboard and below that, a grid with all the list of data. As a total number of items and their total values need to show on top of the grid distributed among categories, I designed something as per the below screenshot, but want to validate that UX-wise it's ok, or is there a better pattern?

**Screenshot of total section:**

[image]

So in the above design, each box contains below details:

1. Total Profit/Order.
2. Total Record/Order count.
3. Title of that box.

I also tried another way to show data in a grid as shown in the below screenshot.

**Grid Data screenshot:**

[image]

How can I improve this so users can get the idea that 1st one is for what value and 2nd one is for what?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one quick solution for correcting given layout.
[image: Cards With One Major and One Minor Values]

1.Primary Title 
2.Primary Amount 
3.Secondary Amount with title

Hope this helps.

Cheers.